# Series termination on an input pin?

Tags: termination

On a development board, I found this schematic for an up to 100 MHz clock input/output pin hooked up to a 2.54 mm pin header block:

[image: series termination]

The 22 ohm series termination makes sense if the pin is configured as an output, but how should this be driven as an input?  I tested driving it from a ~20 ohm gate with no further termination through the header block (~3 cm of trace including header) and while everything works, there is a fair amount of over/undershoot visible on the scope due to reflections as compared to parallel terminated pins.  What is the best practice in this situation?

Comment: Add ~33 ohm back (source) termination resistor at the output of the driver.  This should improve the overshoot & undershoot you said is occurring.  Note, I'm assuming that the traces are designed and built for ~50 ohm impedance.

Comment: We did such series "termination" to reduce transmitted noise for EMI compliance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect they are using  3.3V logic which can vary around 22 Ohms +/-25 to 50% depending on the chip.  The R makes no difference going into a 10K ESD protection resistor or a 1pF ESD diode or the 2pF gate capacitance.

You only need to match the driver to the transmission line, but if there is a mismatch then load capacitance will make a difference.

You can play with my [simulation with transmission line length and](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCMCmC0kCYoIHQFYBsCCcYEe0gGYNIAWSNENCKm6uSSAKEgHZIpEpskiAOMjyQQY8CGwgYhYVhxAChkXtW7KRUONihgpM5gCcQ04VAymICBMwDuZkAkxckj87Lto1KtGSUr3qi5OPkKu4IbUvg4IQiEOTqK6SbrMAG72YZDm6uAOOslJUCgYbEUYbuDozADmxmxB5iUu9bmytYrx5h0ILRBtgZ0DPRqyRkxIOSY5ltZGcVaxUdPRzADG1CoLGw25CIxI8Chk-GjYZNhoROQIgjduKLosHpsxkaGvAac78wnMAM5vUxfCxQEAAMwAhgAbP7QWzbIEvfR2KYYPQWeHjMyiLwif7GJRo5zY1rg6Gw5hkMBEBQufj8ElENAaNgAfWkrLArLIJAQrLQnJQkE5rL5bKIlOpIDIU24wPYFTI7KVXMQaB8-PQTDOTLY-EgeH1J0FSWFXL5SolVJpiAZWMybAqymVIp5WH5grNotZzoltXtTntvXCABMCaIVE1TBMAHJoDgsABKdQmkZaCtJVIUKBpfUqaHh0hmQiLGLDUbCpbCsfjTAiaIZWyrH3yKRRYEbr2BW1kAAdw9EhPVi6C%20oWs02J79rQPbSBHXb-AphRyuW6%20QKwEKRSwgA) impedance mismatch, mouse click switches etc. I added ESD protection which also clamps ringing.

Comment: Thanks, that simulation is really helpful. After simulating a few different digital traces on my board and calculating the overshoot, I'm wondering when it becomes a problem?  The design I have works, but some of my digital buses apparently have over a volt of overshoot (at least for a few hundred picoseconds).  Should I trust that the clamp diodes handle that or do I really want (for example) 32 series resistors on my bus driver IC?

Comment: add the 2nd stage 10k + clamp diodes to simulation if you want to see how well clamps work. It's the margin near threshold that determines SNR BER

Answer (score 1):

You say that's a clock input/output -- presumably, the 22\$\Omega\$ resistor is there to terminate it when it's used as an output.

If I were driving it, I'd put the proper series termination on my output.  The extra series termination probably slows things down, so I'd verify that things still work.  If I were certain that I'd never use that pin as an output I might either replace it with a zero-ohm jumper, or see if there's an opportunity to replace the series termination with a parallel one (official or not).  That kind of depends on having a handy ground plane available at the right place though.